# Have DataAdapter get the new version of modified table

Tags: .net, oracle

I have a .Net app that loads a table from an Oracle Database. The code has to load data dynamically (from any table).

My code is very simple

```
    Dim Command As OracleCommand
    Dim DataAdapter As OracleDataAdapter
    Dim DataSet as DataSet

    Command = New OracleCommand("Select * from MyTable", Me.Connection) 'The connection object is set somewhere else
    Command.CommandType = CommandType.Text

    DataAdapter = New OracleDataAdapter(Command)
    DataAdapter.FillSchema(DataSet, SchemaType.Source, "MyTable")
    DataAdapter.Fill(DataSet, "MyTable")
```

When executing this code the first time, everything works fine. However if I add a field in the table MyTable from the database side using SQL developper, the new field is not available in the table returned by the DataAdapter and I need to restart my application to get it taken into account.

Is there any caching somewhere within the DataAdapter or OracleCommand to be flushed ?

Does anyone know how to solve that please ?

Thanks, cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer :

OracleDataAdapter has the property : **Requery**

If it's set to true, each subsequent Fill call reexecutes the query and fills the DataSet.

Source : 
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/odpnt/featRequery.html#GUID-D7A62257-0676-4B30-A85A-AEBD62D904B2